# C# universal platform audio merge or input in video

Tags: c#, audio, video, merge, uwp

I try to input a .aac in .mp4

as we known

```
ffmpeg cmd
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i video.mp4 -c copy output
```

How to do it in c# uwp, i have search in google i not see this any result regarding this issue , everyone has posted converting issue.

But how to merge it with c# any sample prj or information will be great

Answer (score 5):

> C# universal platform audio merge or input in video

UWP provide APIs about this requirement. This feature can be implemented in uwp by [`BackgroundAudioTracks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.backgroundaudiotracks.aspx) method of [`MediaComposition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.aspx) class. Details for how to do please reference [Add a background audio track to a composition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing#add-a-background-audio-track-to-a-composition). And you can find a sample from scenario 3 of [MediaEditing official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaEditing).

For example:

```
  // Create the original MediaComposition
  var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(pickedFile);
  composition = new MediaComposition();
  composition.Clips.Add(clip);

  // Add background audio
  var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
  picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
  picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
  picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
  picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".flac");
  var audioFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
  if (audioFile == null)
  {
      rootPage.NotifyUser("File picking cancelled", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
      return;
  }

  var backgroundTrack = await BackgroundAudioTrack.CreateFromFileAsync(audioFile);
  composition.BackgroundAudioTracks.Add(backgroundTrack);

  // Render to MediaElement
  mediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
  mediaStreamSource = composition.GeneratePreviewMediaStreamSource((int)mediaElement.ActualWidth, (int)mediaElement.ActualHeight);
  mediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamSource);
```

The `MediaComposition` is created from the video file. The [`BackgroundAudioTrack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.editing.backgroundaudiotrack.aspx) is created from the Mp3 or other audio files you want to merge to the video.  At last, we need to [render the `MediaComposition` to file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn640551.aspx)(the sample is render to `MediaElement` for playing).

Comment: render the MediaComposition to file genereted resolution get so low is there a way to get clone of the mp4 file with the audio

Comment: @AsifShariar,  `MediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync` has several overload methods,  with [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn652696.aspx), you may  assign `MediaEncodingProfile` to what you want to keep quality. If you still have issue when you using these parameters, you can open a new thread. thanks for understanding.

Comment: It works but the file size too big ; suppose i use create mp4 HD1080p , my default file resolution also 1080 p but that size 50 mb and the .aac 2 mb, so total 52 mb , so after encode that with the sound by creating new mp4 HD1080p by Rendering file size get 400 mb , any solution about it

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<StorageFile> MergeVideoAudioAsync(StorageFile videoFile, StorageFile audioFile, string finalFileName, StorageFolder destinationFolder)
    {
        MediaComposition composition = new MediaComposition();
        var file = await destinationFolder.CreateFileAsync(finalFileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(videoFile);
        composition.Clips.Add(clip);
        var backgroundTrack = await BackgroundAudioTrack.CreateFromFileAsync(audioFile);
        composition.BackgroundAudioTracks.Add(backgroundTrack);
        await composition.RenderToFileAsync(file);
        return file;
    }
```