# Merge Audio and Video on Uno Platform

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, webassembly, uno-platform

I am trying to merge an audio stream and a video stream into a single file, on the Uno Platform, particularly for WebAssembly.
I already know that the normal, desktop-only way is by calling `ffmpeg`, and I also found a C# only way for UWP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839751/c-sharp-universal-platform-audio-merge-or-input-in-video).
However, the code used `Windows.Media.Editing` which is [not implemented in Uno](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/Uno.UWP/Generated/3.0.0.0/Windows.Media.Editing/MediaComposition.cs).
I know there is a `ffmpeg` library port for WASM [here](https://ffmpegwasm.github.io), but I don't know how to call it from my Uno web application.

So are there any ways to merge an audio stream and a video stream to a single file, on the Uno platform for WASM?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this API is not yet implemented in Uno Platform, so in this case you need to write platform-specific implementation.

If you have a JavaScript library available, which can provide the functionality you need, you can still call it from the C# code. There is  [a three-part tutorial](https://qa.website.platform.uno/docs/articles/interop/wasm-javascript-1.html) in the Uno Platform docs on implementing C# - JS interop, so that may be helpful to get started.

Alternatively, in case you find an alternative implementation in C# on NuGet, you can install it for the supported platforms and use it in your code as well. To write platform-specific code, you can use `#if` conditionals like `#if __WASM__` etc. - for full information see [this documentation page](https://qa.website.platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-csharp.html).

Comment: The docs does not say much about marshalling objects between C# and js other than `string`s.

Comment: That's correct, marshalling is not documented because it's a work in progress. For ffmpeg, the library needs to be rebuilt to expose its C APIs, not Javascript ones, so PInvoke can be used and avoid explicit marshalling.